# Idiomatic `Number` object to number literal conversion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, literals, idioms

#### `Number` function

```
> var x = new Number(5)
> x === 5
false
> Number(x) === 5
true
```

#### `valueOf` method

```
> var y = new Number(5)
> y === 5
false
> y.valueOf() === 5
true
```

---

Which is the preferred option? Are there benefits to using one over the other?

For the record, I'm dealing with `this` within a method on `Number.prototype`, where I can be sure that `this` is always a `Number` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think the `valueOf` is preferred, since `Number` conversion is meant to be used with values that are not already `Number` objects, but moreover - `Number(x)` will call `valueOf` method on `x`,
so essentially, you'd add an unnecessary sugar/overhead, where `valueOf` is a perfectly accepted way of receiving a primitive representation of an object (`Number` in your case).

As a side note:

> For the record, I'm dealing with this within a method on
>   Number.prototype, where I can be sure that this is always a Number
>   object.

this is not correct as there is always a possibility that someone will do something like this:

```
Number.prototype.test = function()
    {
        console.log(this);
    }

var x = new Number(10);
x.test();

var foo = x.test;
foo();
```

would of course provide:

```
Number
DOMWindow
```

as output. It's for you to decide whether you want to defend against it.

Comment: Thanks, ZenMaster. Your case for `valueOf` is convincing. Thanks also for pointing out that the value of `this` depends on the way in which the function is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Number objects? I think you are just making life difficult. To convert a Number object to a number primitive you can use the '+' operator:

```
var x = new Number(5);
var y = new Number(5);
alert(x == y); // false
alert(+x == +y); // true
```

For fun:

```
Number.prototype.whatIsThis = function() {return typeof this;};

var x = new Number(5);
var y = 5;
alert( x.whatIsThis());  // Object
alert( y.whatIsThis());  // Object

alert( y ==   x );  // True
alert( y ===  x );  // False
alert( y === +x );  // True
```

Comment: I'm not *creating* `Number` objects. I'm referencing `this` within "getters" attached to properties of `Number.prototype`. It's just what `this` happens to be. See [mathmethods.js](https://bitbucket.org/davidchambers/mathmethods.js) for the code in question.

Comment: Ok, thought that might be it. I'd just use the unary "+" operator, since `Number(this)` may not be obvious—and more to type. :-)